# RESTFul service call to Remote EJB method (Synchronous) behaves Asynchronously in JBOSS 6.4

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jboss

We implemented a Restful service which in turn calls a Remote EJB method, the problem is before the EJB TXN completes or while it is running, the restful service get backs the control.

Here Caller(Restful service) and Invoked EJB method execution runs in parallel. And EJB commits properly, no issue in commit.
Our Restful service call to EJB method behaving like a asynch call to that EJB. In brief -> Restful service calls the EJB, not waiting until the EJB returns, get back the control and ends, in the meantime EJB also runs independently and commits.

And our EJBs are synchronous only and even Restful service don't have any explicit &Asynch annotations.

We need our Restful service to wait until the EJB returns back it's response.

Same scenario works as we expected in weblogic server. But in JBOSS the above described issue occurs everytime.

Comment: What about the return value of the remote EJB method? If the method returns void try to return a value like the current milliseconds to see if the return value gets through synchronously.

Comment: our EJB method is not returning void.

Comment: Now i found onething, this issue is happening because of the underlying error -> javax.ejb.EJBException: java.io.IOException:  Remoting connection has been closed.

Comment: Is there a way to increase the Remote Connection wait time?

Answer (score 0):

Now I could find the issue is with the below configuration in Standalone.xml,

```
<remote connector-ref="remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default">
             <channel-creation-options>
  <option name="WORKER_READ_THREADS" value="2" type="xnio"/>
  <option name="WORKER_WRITE_THREADS" value="2" type="xnio"/>
  <option name="MAX_INBOUND_MESSAGES" value="150" type="remoting"/>
   <option name="MAX_OUTBOUND_MESSAGES" value="150" type="remoting"/>
   </channel-creation-options>
</remote>
            <thread-pools>
                <thread-pool name="default">
                    <max-threads count="150"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="200" unit="minutes"/>
                </thread-pool>
            </thread-pools>
             <in-vm-remote-interface-invocation pass-by-value="false"/>
```

When I increased the max-threads count and keepaline-time, sometimes it's working without any issue. But still I get the above mentioned error sometimes. How to decide the appropriate value for the above configuration in standalone.xml